# Undo/Redo removing elements from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app where users can draw elements, remove them, move them, resize them etc. I want to be able to undo/redo almost every single action in my app, without refreshing the page.

So for example, when I remove an element by pressing backspace, I'd like to be able to undo that action by pressing 'CMD+Z' and redo it by pressing'CMD+Shift+Z' .

**JS**

```
// Remove selected element
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) {
      $(".ui-selected").remove();
      return false;
  }
});
```

I need a solution that I can reuse for almost every action in my app. I'm not sure if this informs the solution, but I'm storing all of these changes in local storage with [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).

Comment: Keep an array that stores all of the changes that way when you want to undo, all you have to do is navigate backwards from the current index in the array, then if a change is made, remove all changes that are after that since you're now in a new branch.

Comment: Is there a plugin I can use?

Comment: possibly, but i don't know of any. seems like a simple enough concept to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time this is done using the command pattern, where for each "do" command an "undo" command is stored in an array, and traversing backwards and forwards invokes those commands.

http://jsperf.com/undo-redo has a list of undo scripts with performance benchmarks. I haven't used any of those as I had my own itch to scratch a while back when I wrote https://github.com/ArthurClemens/Javascript-Undo-Manager.